# Define utils function available for all views in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I have a few functions I would like to be available in all my views (like utils functions). Where should I put them ? Is it better to add them to all my directives, or to a common directive ?

Comment: Depends if you like to maintain lots of code in different places or not?

Comment: All jokes aside, have a central point for common stuff, like a util service, then have the directives make use of said service

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm a huge fan of [DRY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don't_repeat_yourself)...

Unless there is a proven performance benefit of not re-factoring the code and having the said logic scattered over multiple files... wrap it in a service, or central controller if you have one already (all of which should be aptly named of course to make sense), and then have the "child" controllers make use of the service (if you decided to go the service route).

Comment: Just out of interest... I've asked this question on Programmers.StackExchange. http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/280386/should-we-always-dry-any-edge-case-examples-of-when-not-to

Answer (score 0):

You could put them in a parent controller doing something like this:

```
<div ng-controller="MainCtrl as main">
  <div ui-view></div>
</div>
```